# Windows7 RSS Wallpaper Theme

Tags: windows-7, rss, themes

I've spent a few days fighting with this and have come asking if anyone can see what I'm doing wrong. I am trying to make use of the Windows7 RSS Theme. As, in concept, it sounds wickedly cool to be able to define my desktop as a FEED URL.

However, in practice I find as per usual I am getting boned by Microsoft insisting on taking a standard feature set and creating a broken proprietary subset.

They say you need to have the image in an enclosure, but finding a clear example of what that shoud **look** like, is harder than finding articles talking about how it works.  Below is a general template of what I've been trying.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
<rss version='2.0' xmlns:cf='http://www.microsoft.com/schemas/rss/core/2005'>
  <channel>
    <cf:treatAs>list</cf:treatAs>
    <title>FeedTitle</title>
    <link>[link to feed]</link>
    <description>Windows Backgrounds RSS</description>
    <language>en-us</language>
    <cf:listinfo>
      <cf:sort label="Relevance" default="true" />
    </cf:listinfo>

    <item>
      <link rel='enclosure' type='image/jpg' href='[imagelink]' />
      <title>[title text]</title>
      <link>[post src url]</link>
      <pubDate>Mon, 29 Dec 2014 05:13:03 PST</pubDate>
      <description>&lt;div&gt;HTML Entity Encoded Description&lt;/div&gt;</description>
    </item>
    .
    .
    .
  </channel>
</rss>
```

I would greatly appreciate any in-site to making this go, I have a grand idea of setting the script to contextually rotate source material and to be able to subscribe multiple locations to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind!  I got it working myself,

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes'?>
<feed xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:dc='http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/' xmlns:flickr='urn:flickr:user' xmlns:media='http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/'>
    <title>Fun Feeds</title>
    <link rel='self' href='[Url of Feed]' />

    <entry>
      <link rel='enclosure' type='image/jpg' href='[Link to Image]' />
      <title>[Post Title]</title>
      <link rel='alternate' type='text/html' href='[Link to Post]'/>
      <published>Mon, 29 Dec 2014 05:13:03 PST</published>
      <content tyle='html'>[Post Text]</content>
    </entry>
</feed>
```

As I was asking the question, I realized I wasn't completely sure I had exactly duplicated the style of the flickr feed when I tried it the first time. Because there was a lot going on, after carefully matching all the tags up this time it finally worked, I think it also had to do with a Caching issue.
Anyways, I'll leave this here as a format template for others If you'd like to have a dynamic background. Remember to make sure your first line sets your headers:
`<?php  header('Content-Type: application/rss+xml; charset=utf-8'); ?>`

If you need help getting started goto `%systemroot%\Globalization\MCT\` and pick one of the theme folders there, inside a region folder is a final Theme directory. Create a copy of the *.theme* file to use as your starting point. Find or add the section **[SlideShow]**

```
[Slideshow]
Interval=1800000
Shuffle=1
```

Then choose EITHER

```
RssFeed=http://www.link.to/custom/rss.php
```

or

```
ImagesRootPath=%SystemRoot%\
Item0Path=%SystemRoot%\Globalization\MCT\MCT-CA\Wallpaper\CA-wp1.jpg
Item1Path=%SystemRoot%\Globalization\MCT\MCT-CA\Wallpaper\CA-wp2.jpg
```

If you go the Image root path, you need to add each full file path and increment Item2 as you go.
Once you are ready, you can select your new file and hit [Enter] the personalization window should open right up and you can finish adjusting your settings and save your new profile.

If you go the RSS route, the first time when you click on Desktop Background it should ask if you want to save the content. Say yes, and apparently you are required to have Shuffle set for it to work.